# How can I access my iCloud files on my Mac?

Tags: mac, icloud

When I save a file that I've written in TextEdit, it saves to iCloud by default. If I close the file, and close TextEdit, the only way for me to find that file is by searching it in Spotlight and opening it. I can't find a folder on my computer that contains those files. When I right click the file that shows up in Spotlight there is no option to open enclosing folder. I tried going on icloud.com and logging into my account but I couldn't just get a simple list of the files I had saved on the cloud.

Where are my iCloud files? And how I can I remove them from iCloud?

I've been looking online for about an hour at this point for an answer to this question and am stunned that I haven't found one/anyone else with the same problem. I'm sure I must be missing something very obvious.

Comment: Have you already look in Home/Library/Mobile Documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iCloud files are cached on your Mac, so you can access them even when you have no internet connection. They are stored in `~/Library/Mobile Documents/`.

To make it even more accessible, you can add the folder in your sidebar.

There you'll see that each application has it's own folder with it's own documents. Files can be added or removed in this window.
To make sure you're working in your iCloud, you can try and delete a file. Your Mac will notify you, you're deleting the file in iCloud.